# How widely known are Iverson brackets?

Tags: soft-question, notation, article-writing

Here on the Mathematics Stack Exchange I recently learned about the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) notation:

$$[P] = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } P \text{ is true;} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

It occurs to me that using this notation would greatly simplify many of the equations in a computer science thesis I'm writing.  However, I'm not sure how widely known it is.  I don't remember coming across it in my undergraduate and graduate studies, though perhaps this is one of those things that everyone but me seems to know.

My question: For what types of readers would it be safe to use Iverson brackets without explanation, and for what audiences would it be better to first introduce them with a definition as above?

Comment: Seeing as Kenneth Iverson (of APL fame) was a well known computer scientist, and Donald Knuth, another famous computer scientist, wrote a polemic in favor of Iverson brackets, I would **hope** that they would be widely known to a CS audience. But I agree with your answerers: define them anyway!

Comment: @bof, you stole my comment.

Comment: Your thesis will include a table of your notational conventions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's always better to err on the safe side. If you have any doubt at all that your intended audience needs a reminder about notation, make sure to include the relevant definitions. That also makes sure that there is no doubt about edge cases (sometimes terms have almost standard definitions, but with some subtle differences).

Comment: +1. The worst thing that could happen is a referee writing, "there's no need to define this as everyone knows". One might object that this is impossible, to what I would agree if I didn't know already that there are some referees acting impossibly out there.

Comment: @zhoraster: a stickler referee objecting on that would be great news, meaning that he found no worse flaw ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would sat just to specify somewhere early in the paper that you are planning on using that notation. But, I would recommend erring on the safe side and consulting with your supervisor